# Older devices and AndroidManifest configChanges "screenSize"

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, screen-size, android-configchanges

Quoting the documentation:

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
>   also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
>   orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
>   orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
>   declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
>   must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
>   value. That is, you must decalare
>   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

I need to ignore the `screenSize` config change. My minimum SDK level is 8 (Android 2.2), and target SDK level is 13. Therefore, I need to introduce it in the manifest.

However, Eclipse doesn't recognize it, because its Android setting is set to 2.2. So I've changed it to the proper level, and now it builds properly.

I'm afraid, however, that there will be issues on older versions where the `screenSize` config change wasn't yet available. (E.g. when the app is run on Android 2.2. device.) That is, the application will crash when it reads the manifest, because `screenSize` will be an unknown value for it. Or will it simply ignore it on pre-3.2 devices?

P.S.: I don't have the chance to test it on a real device now, and I wouldn't trust the emulator alone in such a critical matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will ignore it. Same is true for splitscreen action bar and other things that are similar. Unlike in java, any things the android os doesn't understand from the manifest it essentially ignores.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: It gets ignored.

As a rule, values in the manifest that aren't recognized (like screenSize on a pre-2.2 device) get ignored for precisely this reason.  Otherwise it wouldn't be possible for developers to use functionality added in new platform versions, without breaking backwards compatibility for older devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I set AndroidPenguin's answer as accepted because he posted first. I upvoted yours.

Comment: Sorry that I beat you by literally a minute :P upvoted yours though all the same =)

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes! No worries, I'm totally unsurprised that someone beat me to posting the answer.  As long as it's the correct one, I don't mind at all :)