# orientation change happening but not getting handler called in android 2.3.3

Tags: android

I have based my code for 2.3.3 and testing on device 4.0.4
Orientation change works on activity but I am not able to get the orientation change handler.

Although i have added to stuff required but am not sure it is complete
This is what i have added

mainfest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
```

Acivity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try adding "screenSize" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062663/older-devices-and-androidmanifest-configchanges-screensize)

Comment: screenSize is not available in 2.3.3

Comment: I know, but this is why you are having the problem on 4.0.4. Just set your project to use 4.X, add screenSize, set the right minSDK values, and test again.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt understand. I have to make the code compatible to 2.3.3 devices...

Comment: 2.3.3 devices will ignore it, don't worry.